# Why text is overflowed HTML button?

Tags: html, button

I have following HTML button in my webpage:

[image: Html menu button]

The buttons have to be fixed width and if texts overflow it's width it should be wrapped by `white-space:normal`. The `Search Staff (F2)` and `Select Item(F3)` are wrapped correctly. But don't know why `Company(F8)` and `Product(F4)` buttons are not wrapping inside button. Here is the HTML layout for those button:

```css
.menu_button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #D0D0D0;
  color: #0000FF;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-width: 4px;
  white-space: normal;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="option_bar">
  <input id="check" type="button" class="menu_button" name="list_item" value="Item&#13;&#10;(F1)" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input id="check" type="button" class="menu_button" name="company" value="Company(F8)" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="button" class="menu_button" name="search" value="Search Staff&#13;&#10;(F2)" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="button" class="menu_button" name="select_item" value="Select Item&#13;&#10;(F3)" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="button" class="menu_button" name="product" value="Products&#13;&#10;(F4)" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="button" class="menu_button" name="bid" value="Bid&#13;&#10;(F6)" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="button" class="menu_button" name="letter" value="Letter&#13;&#10;(F7)" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="button" class="menu_button" name="price" value="Price&#13;&#10;(F9)" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="button" class="menu_button" name="print" value="Print&#13;&#10;(F12)" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
</div>
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Give a space to make the text break.. else this is the default behaviour..

Comment: Because these buttons consist of one word. If you separate them to two words they will wrap

Comment: Remove width so it can take necessary space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a space before the open bracket.

Comment: Most of the above solutions are correct. But as @manmeet Gill answered at first, I accepted his answer. Thanks to all of you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `word-wrap` property.

`The word-wrap property allows long words to be able to be broken and wrap onto the next line.`

CSS syntax:

`word-wrap: normal|break-word|initial|inherit;`

```
p.test {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Another way you can the same result is add an space between parenthesis and the last word letter.

Answer (score 0):

Add space to before "(F8)" and before "(f4)"

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve from this, but still you can add space between "Company" and "(F8)", that would do exactly what you require like in `Search Staff (F2)`, similarly you can do this for `Product (F4)`.

```
<div id="option_bar">
<input id="check" type="button" class="menu_button" name="list_item" value="Item&#13;&#10;(F1)" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input id="check" type="button" class="menu_button" name="company" value="Company (F8)" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="button" class="menu_button" name="search" value="Search Staff&#13;&#10;(F2)" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="button" class="menu_button" name="select_item" value="Select Item&#13;&#10;(F3)" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="button" class="menu_button" name="product" value="Products&#13;&#10;(F4)" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="button" class="menu_button" name="bid" value="Bid&#13;&#10;(F6)" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="button" class="menu_button" name="letter" value="Letter&#13;&#10;(F7)" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="button" class="menu_button" name="price" value="Price&#13;&#10;(F9)" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="button" class="menu_button" name="print" value="Print&#13;&#10;(F12)" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
```